# How to use wget to download a dataset

Tags: terminal, curl, wget

I want to download the dataset in [this website](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/food-101/data) (where it says "Download (5GB)" near the blue "New Notebook" button).  When opening that link in a new tab([this link](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/food-101/data)) it launches the download immediately.  How can I do this via the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Javascript, where clicking on a single link is made difficult by lots of Javascript intervening and "protecting" the download.

The simplest way to download it from the commandline is probably to enable web developer tools in your browser (whatever your browser it; I don't know, so I can't give details), click on the link, have a look what goes on in the "Network" tab, identify the URL of the actual download, and copy this e.g. as a curl command using the menu item provided by the web developer tools.

Note that this link will probably contain headers which will ensure it only works for a limited time.